# Why geom_rect looking different across facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm trying to color different quadrants of a plot that is also being faceted. I'm noticing that the colors from the `geom_rect` argument look different across facets. Here's what I hope is a example:

```
# Load tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# Make some fake data
set.seed(5)
dat <- tibble(
  y = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  ub = y + .2,
  lb = y - .2,
  x = sample(1:7, size=10, replace=TRUE),
  z = sample(c("one", "two", "three"), size=10, replace=TRUE),
)

# Plot
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL, aes(xmin=4, xmax=Inf, ymin=0, ymax=-Inf), fill="yellow", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL, aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=4, ymin=Inf, ymax=0), fill="yellow", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL, aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=4, ymin=-Inf, ymax=0), fill="red", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  geom_rect(data=NULL, aes(xmin=4, xmax=Inf, ymin=0, ymax=Inf), fill="springgreen", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  geom_point(position= position_dodge2(width = .6)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lb, ymax = ub, width = .6), position= position_dodge2(width = .6, preserve = "single")) +
  facet_grid(~ z) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: This is what the result looks like]

Can anyone explain to me why the `geom_rect` boxes are brighter in some facets compared to others? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that `geom_rect` is overlaying rectangles on top of each other each time it's called. If you sort the facets you'll see that the second is less transparent than the first, and the third less transparent than the second.

The solution is to use `annotate` instead of `geom_rect`:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(z = factor(z, levels = c("one", "two", "three"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=4, xmax=Inf, ymin=0, ymax=-Inf, fill="yellow", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=-Inf, xmax=4, ymin=Inf, ymax=0, fill="yellow", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=-Inf, xmax=4, ymin=-Inf, ymax=0, fill="red", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  annotate("rect", xmin=4, xmax=Inf, ymin=0, ymax=Inf, fill="springgreen", color = "white", alpha = .05) +
  geom_point(position= position_dodge2(width = .6)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lb, ymax = ub, width = .6), position= position_dodge2(width = .6, preserve = "single")) +
  facet_grid(~ z) +
  theme_classic()
```

Result:

[image]